# Email verification in Spring Roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo, email-verification

I need to make kind of email verification when the user creates a new account, how can I achieve that? Is it a service provided by the web host or I need to program it manually? I couldn't find useful info when searching.

Answer (score 2):

You should program it yourself. You can look at [this post](https://spring.io/blog/2009/05/27/getting-started-with-spring-roo) which explains how to configure security and how to send a email but you must put all this together to archive it.

In the other hand, you could look a [gvNIX](http://www.gvnix.org/en/index.html) *typical-security add-on* which generates a security-configuration approach which can be useful to you.

Good luck!